# Firebase orderByChild once child_added is only giving one child

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

For simplicity's sake, let's say I have a database with the following structure:

```
project
└── users
    ├── safuhf8sdf76fs
    │   ├── name: 'William'
    │   └── age: 19
    ├── sffuef5srf72fd
    │   ├── name: 'Emily'
    │   └── age: 20
    └── rfdu4ffsgf42gi
        ├── name: 'Sam'
        └── age: 24
```

Let's also say that I'm trying to retrieve users with ages less than or equal to 22 in a Firebase Cloud Function. This function can be fired at any arbitrary time and should query the users with matching age conditions as above.

I thought I could do this:

```
admin.database().ref('users').orderByChild('age').endAt(22).once('child_added', function (snapshot) {

// perform logic with each user snapshot

});
```

But this only returns one user each time it's called- albeit it does provide the youngest user as specified by `orderByChild`. In this example, it only returns the user William, and not Emily. But if I remove William from the db, then it returns Emily the next time, so I know that Emily also met the criteria.

[The Retrieving Data docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#child-added) suggest that this should run once for each child as I desire but that isn't happening and I don't know why. Maybe it has something to do with using `.once` instead of `.on` but I don't wish to retain the reference. I want it to perform the logic and then immediately drop the reference.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: What about `.once('value')`?

Comment: Using `value` instead of `child_added` returns the entire `users` tree (with the children that match the criteria) instead of the children themselves. Technically I could make it work this way but in my situation it's pretty counter-intuitive.

Comment: `.once('child_added')` won't work, it only gives you the first child. `.on('child_added')` won't work either because you won't know when you've got all the children. You'll need to use `.once('value')`. If you're not sure how to make that work with the logic you're performing, we'll need to see that code.

Comment: Well I'm guessing that I'll just have to iterate through each object in `snapshot` since using `value` will put them all into one large tree (with two objects in this example)

Comment: Exactly. Don't forget to use `snapshot.val()` of course.

Comment: Perfect, this works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `.once()` will trigger the callback just the first time you add a child, which should be William. Instead if you use `.on()` it'll trigger the callback each time a child that meets the criteria is added, i.e. once for William and another for Emily.

Also you should check the event that will trigger your callback. You want this to happen just the first time you add a child, you want it to happen every time you add a new child, you want it to happen just when you call the function, or every time you add change the value.

Comment: What would be the best way to immediately remove the reference once the logic has been completed? This is in cloud functions so I need the reference to be removed.

Comment: This function is not triggered by database events, but rather an HTTP trigger. I need to query the applicable users one time and then drop all references until the next HTTP trigger.

Comment: If you use `.once()` you won't need to remove the reference. It'll happen just when you call your function and no more.

Comment: But `.once` only gives the first child, and I need all applicable children, so I guess I have to use `.on`

Comment: No, `.once('value')` will give you all the children that meet the criteria, just _once_. Instead, if you use `.on('value')` it'll give you all the children that meet the criteria everytime the value of the reference (i.e. `users`) is changed.

Comment: Right now I'm using `.once('child_added')` and that is only returning one child. Do I have to use `.once('value')`? Using `value` gives the entire tree of users in one snapshot, so then I think I'd have to iterate through the tree. Is this what you're suggesting?

Comment: The problem is you are triggering the callback when a child that meets the criteria is added, but it triggers just once. The event `'value'` would trigger the callback with all the children. If You use `'.once('value')` yes, you would have to iterate through all the children.

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
 admin.database().ref('users').orderByChild('age').endAt(22)
     .once('value', function (snapshot) {...})
```

or:

```
admin.database().ref('users').orderByChild('age').endAt(22)
.once('value').then((snapshot)=> {...})
```

`snapshot.val()` will contain an **object** with all the queried children